# error: expected ‘;’ before ‘generationString’

Tags: c++, output, ostream

I'm currently trying to work out some issues I am experiencing with this code, can't really figure out why I am getting these 2 errors.
I tried to see if something was not closed, but this not does seem to be the case, can be be cause of the distance between the ": "? 
I'm just grasping for straws by now..

```
main.cpp:30:38: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘generationString’
cout << "Generation " << x << ": " generationString << endl;

main.cpp:54:40: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘generationString’
cout << "Generation " << x++ << ": " generationString << endl;
```

When trying to compile this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string
initString ()
{
}

int
calculateScore (string guess, string target)
{
}

string
mutate (string mutationString)
{
}


int
main ()
{
  string targetString = "METHINKS IT IS LIKE A WEASEL";
  string generationString = initString ();
  string currentString = generationString;

  int score = calculateScore (currentString, targetString);
  int x = 0;
  cout << "Generation " << x << ": " generationString << endl;
  do
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
      string newCopy = generationString;
      newCopy = mutate (newCopy);
      int copyScore = calculateScore (newCopy, targetString);

      if (copyScore > score)
        {
      currentString = newCopy;
      score = copyScore;
      if (copyScore == targetString.length ())
    {
      break;
    }

    }
}
  generationString = currentString;

     }
  while (score < targetString.length ());
  cout << "Generation " << x++ << ": " generationString << endl;
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: `": " generationString` -> `": " << generationString`. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Yeah, definitely typo issue. 
If you post this seperately I can add as answer.

Comment: Typo issues are meant to be flagged as such. Not to be answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `<<`.

```
cout << "Generation " << x << ": " generationString << endl;
```

Should be

```
cout << "Generation " << x << ": " << generationString << endl;
```

Likewise for

```
cout << "Generation " << x++ << ": " generationString << endl;
```

That should be

```
cout << "Generation " << x++ << ": " << generationString << endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are probably missing a `<<` in the line

```
cout << "Generation " << x << ": " generationString << endl;
```

Here you have

```
": " generationString
```

which should be

```
": " << generationString
```

C++ can concatenate literal strings, but it cannot concatenate literal string with anything else (like std::strings). So for instance this would work

```
cout << "Generation " << x << ": " "METHINKS IT IS LIKE A WEASEL" << endl;
```